# conditional filtering on rows rather than columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Given a table

|  | col_0 | col_1 | col_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a_00 | a_01 | a_02 |
| 1 | a_10 | nan | a_12 |
| 2 | a_20 | a_21 | a_22 |

If I am returning all rows such col_1 does not contain `nan`, then it can be easily done by `df[df['col_1'].notnull()]`, which returns

|  | col_0 | col_1 | col_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a_00 | a_01 | a_02 |
| 2 | a_20 | a_21 | a_22 |

If I would like to return all columns such that its 1-th row does not contain nan, what should I do? The following is the result that I want:

|  | col_0 | col_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a_00 | a_02 |
| 1 | a_10 | a_12 |
| 2 | a_20 | a_22 |

I can transpose dataframe, remove rows on transposed dataframe, and transpose back, but it would become inefficient if dataframe is huge. I also tried

```
df.loc[df.loc[0].notnull()]
```

but the code gives me an error. Any ideas?

Comment: condition ```notnull()``` is one example, but generically how can I condition on rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boolean indexing with `loc` along columns axis

```
df.loc[:, df.iloc[1].notna()]
```

Result

```
  col_0 col_2
0  a_00  a_02
1  a_10  a_12
2  a_20  a_22
```